# Why is there a break in shacharit between "umakdishim" and "et shem"?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer

In the siddur there is a break in the middle of the sentence "...umakdishim umamlichim.." and "...et shem...".  I there a reason for this, or is it merely poetic?